# How to use generics in a method declaration

Tags: java, generics, hashmap

I have a controller which initializes `HashMap`(**for example**). How I can use the **k and v** in the **Generic Declaration of the HashMap**

```
public static void testMyMethods(Class k, Class v) {
    // Tried the below code, but it is having compile time issues
    HashMap < k.getClass(), v.getClass() > hm = new HashMap < k.getClass(), k.getClass() > ();
}
```

Comment: The types in generics have to be known at compile time to get any benefit out of them. They don't exist at run time so it makes no sense to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Quirliom: Okay, so there isnt any other way, through which we can achieve this?

Comment: Generic is not required to create a HashMap, so you can just use raw type then.

Comment: @SashiKant you could always create Map<Object,Object> and then cast it back when you need it

Comment: @PhamTrung: I took HashMap as an example, I had my own custom class where it will be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Class<?>` is a generic type as well, you can use:

```
public static <K,V> void testMyMethods(Class<K> k, Class<V> v) {
    Map<K, V> hm = new HashMap<>();
    ...
}
```

But as long as you don't use `k` and `v`, you don't need to provide any of them:

```
public static <K, V> void testMyMethods() {
    Map<K, V> hm = new HashMap<>();
    ...
}
```

I changed HashMap to Map in the declaration, see *Effective Java - Item 52* for an explanation.

And I used the diamond operator `<>`, which is available since Java 7.

Comment: There would be no point of having `K` and `V` if they do not show up in the parameters or return type.

Comment: Indeed it is nessecary, as long as K and V are used more then once in the method. It helps to ensure that always the same type is added as key or value - which is not possible for `<Object, Object>`.

Comment: @TobiasLiefke: No it is not. Generic type variables on a method means an outsider can arbitrarily decide what they are and your method must still work. So your method *must* be able to work with `K = Object, V = Object`, and at the same time work with `K = Math, V = String`, without knowing what they are.

Comment: @newacct: That's only partially correct: As there is no restriction on `K` and `V` - it is the same as `<K extends Object, V extends Object>` - I must be able to work with any Object for key and value, indeed. But no caller will enforce any other restriction on K or V. Even calling <Math,String>testMyMethods() won't change that. I'm only creating a contract, that the type of the keys (and values) will be the same throughout the whole method..

Comment: @TobiasLiefke: Therefore, one should just be able to substitute K and V in the source code of the method with Math and String and the method should still compile and work with no difference. Therefore, the type parameters K and V are not necessary.

Answer (score -1):

In Java 7 you can use diamond operator like this

```
HashMap< ?, ? > hm = new HashMap <> ();
```

and `?` indicate undefined type.

and if your really dont know your types then there is not need to telling Java about their types and you can declare like this

```
Map hm = new HashMap <> ();
```

Comment: I don't think we can add anything into this hashmap if you are using wildcard

Comment: Yes its a wildcard type, but my requirement is a bit different.. :)

Comment: @ Pham question was relating to declaring so there is my solution. but if someone really dont know types then they dont need to tell Java their types and use just HashMap without types. i have updated my answer which answer your question :)

Comment: Raw types are provided for backward compatibility - you shouldn't use them (as long as you aren't using old APIs).

Comment: @PhamTrung: except `null` :)

Comment: "same as Map<Object, Object> hm = new HashMap <> ();" No they are not the same

Comment: @ newacct : both behave like same .. so whats the difference ?

Comment: @MuhammadSuleman: For example, you can assign a `Map<String, Integer>` to a `Map` but not a `Map<Object, Object>`.